# Parse type name of function to human readable text for logs - wildcard

Tags: c#, regex, wildcard

How can I take a full type name of a function such as :

```
  MyApp.Components.Services.<SomeMethodName>d__e.MoveNext
```

And parse it into something like

```
  Components.Services.SomeMethodName()
```

I could have gotten by via simple Replace() calls, however what messes me up is the "d__e" which can vary. In reality I need to wildcard a few characters. Something like `">*__*.MoveNext"`

How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negated character class instead of `*` in `">*__*.MoveNext"`

Regex:

```
MyApp.(Components.Services.)<([^<>]*)>[^_]*__[^.]*.MoveNext
```

Replacement string:

```
$1$2()
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hW6hZ3/1)

**Code:**

```
string str = "foo bar MyApp.Components.Services.<SomeMethodName>d__e.MoveNext";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"MyApp.(Components.Services.)<([^<>]*)>[^_]*__[^.]*.MoveNext", "$1$2()");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/WeRDS9)

Comment: I'm not following. I need to do this in c# code. demo doesn't work

Comment: added according to your wish.